# Grabbing radio button values but having variable issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Edit, Update!**

Thanks a lot Shailendra Sharma for your help :) Everyone's answers taught me something though, so thanks everyone!

---

First, here is my problem:

I am trying to make it so that when a radio button is clicked, it will add the value of the radio button, in both form fields, into two different variables (selection1 and 2)

After that, it will add those paths to the $htmlImagePath variable. After the user clicks on two selections, it will complete that path and it will be an image source path, at which point I will have code that will append that complete path to the HTML and show an image.

Unfortuantely I am running into a problem. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, but the original console.log shows two "objects" where the values should be (in this case, 'cs' and 'schwarz') and when I click on the form buttons, nothing happens.

I've tried a few different things, but I run into similar problems. Completely stuck and my brain is fried right now -.- Help? XD

Here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qk59sk7/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var $htmlImagePath = "<img src='images/";
      var $selection1 = ($("input[type=radio][name='finishes'][value='cs']").prop("checked", true));
      var $selection2 = ($("input[type=radio][name='colours'][value='schwarz']").prop("checked", true));

      $("#finish input:radio").on("click", function() {
          $selection1 = $("#finish input:checked").val(); 
      });

      $htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection1 + '-';

      $("#color input:radio").on ("click", function() {
          $selection2 = $("#color input:checked").val();
      });

      $htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection2 + ".jpg'";
      console.log($htmlImagePath);
  });
```

Here is the HTML

```
 <div id="finish" class="spalte3">
  <p >Ausfuehrungen Rahmen:</p>
   <form>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="finishes" value="cs" class="image_selection">
      <label for="cs">Chrome glanz</label>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input type="radio" name="finishes" value="cbr"   class="image_selection">
     <label for="cbr">Chrome gebuerstet</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="finishes" value="cbl" class="image_selection">
      <label for="cbl">Schwarz verchromt</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="color" class="spalte3">
  <p>Ausfuehrungen Tablare:</p>
   <form>
     <div>
       <input type="radio" name="colours" value="schwarz"  class="image_selection">
       <label for="schwarz">Schwarz</label>
     </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="colours" value="weiss-s" class="image_selection">
      <label for="weiss-s">Weiss</label>
    </div>
     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="colours" value="dunkelrot" class="image_selection">
      <label for="dunkelrot">Dunkelrot</label>
     </div>
     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="colours" value="fango"   class="image_selection">
      <label for="fango">Fango</label>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
 <div id="log" class="spalte3">
    <img class="skizze-res" src="images/poolfinish/cs-schwarz.jpg"   alt="Chrom glanz mit Schwarz">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your code run at page load an object assign to  $htmlImagePath by following way `$htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection1 + '-';`
and as your code this line never execute second time after page  load  that's why  `$htmlImagePath` never update with new value

check out this code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var $htmlImagePath = "<img src='images/";
        var $selection1 = ($("input[type=radio][name='finishes'][value='cs']").prop ("checked", true));
        var $selection2 = ($("input[type=radio][name='colours'][value='schwarz']").prop ("checked", true));

            $("#finish input:radio,#color input:radio").on ("click", function(){
                $selection1 = $("#finish input:checked").val(); 
                $selection2 = $("#color input:checked").val();
                $htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection1 + '-';
                $htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection2 + ".jpg'";
                console.log($htmlImagePath);
         });

    });
```

**[here the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qk59sk7/4/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I found this to be the best answer and I was able to further modify it according to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

That happen because, the variable `$htmlImagePath` was assigned value at run time and store `[object..]` itselft, you should add the value inside click handler both section. Try below code :

```
$("#finish input:radio").on ("click", function(){
    $selection1 = $("#finish input:checked").val(); 
    $htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection1 + '-';
    newPath();
}); 

$("#color input:radio").on ("click", function() {
   $selection2 = $("#color input:checked").val();
   $htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection2 + ".jpg'";
   newPath();
});

function newPath(){
   console.log($htmlImagePath);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/n548xc5r/)

Answer (score 0):

`$selection1` and `$selection2` are JQuery objects, you should use the value they hold, to concatenate, like so:

```
$selection1.val()
$selection2.val()
```

[Here is the update **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1qk59sk7/2/) where the console.log shows `<img src='images/cs-schwarz.jpg'`

corrected lines:

```
$htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection1.val() + '-';

$htmlImagePath = $htmlImagePath + $selection2.val() + ".jpg'";
```